# Same origin policy blocks AJAX token call

Tags: rest-api, jquery, json, oauth2

I need to implement a feed from a client site into their Salesforce system. I'm using the REST API.

I can get an authorization code, but when I try passing it to get an access token using AJAX, it always fails saying I'm violating same origin. I know the posted data works since if I run it in Postman, I get the JSON I expect.

Code is as follows. It's barking about a header on the Salesforce side, but I've set this up. (Whitelisted my domain, given user Modify All Data privilege)

```
$.ajax({
 type:"POST",
 headers: {"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
 dataType:"json",
 crossDomain:true,
 async:false,
 url:"https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token",
 data: {
          "grant-type":"authorization_code",
          "format":"json",
          "client_secret":"{my secret}",
          "client_id":"{my_id}",
          "redirect_uri":"{my_uri}",
          "code":"{auth_code}"
         success:function(data, status, error) { alert(data);}
},


});
```

*EDIT*
Error is always:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token.(Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin missing).
```

I'm under the assumption this is what Salesforce is **supposed** to do when I whitelist my domain?

I'm using a sandbox domain in lightning.force.com. Trying to call the sandbox domain results in the same error.

Comment: can you add errors please ? are you using lightning? or visualforce?  can you share a bit more of your cxode strructure if any? components, apex class... thanks